# Error 1053 when installing Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I created a demo service.

1. Build project as is (Service1 constructor, OnStart, OnStop)
2. Added Installer, changed the required properties.
3. Build project.
4. Open command prompt, run "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" TestService.exe
5. Getting the following error on installation

> C:\Users**>"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUt
>   il.exe" "C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\TestServi ce\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe"
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version > Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the C:\Users**\Documents\Visua l Studio
>   2010\Projects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe
>   assembl y's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Proj
>   ects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly 'C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projec ts\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestS
>   ervice\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.InstallLog    assemblypath =
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\
>   TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe Installing service
>   Service1... Creating EventLog source Service1 in log Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some
>   or all eve nt logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs:
>   Security.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the C:\Users**\Documents\Visua l
>   Studio 2010\Projects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe
>   assembl y's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Proj
>   ects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.InstallLog. Rolling
>   back assembly 'C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Proj ects\TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestS
>   ervice\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.InstallLog    assemblypath =
>   C:\Users**\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\
>   TestService\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe Restoring event log
>   to previous state for source Service1. An exception occurred during
>   the Rollback phase of the System.Diagnostics.EventL ogInstaller
>   installer. System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not
>   found, but some or all eve nt logs could not be searched. 
>   Inaccessible logs: Security. An exception occurred during the Rollback
>   phase of the installation. This except ion will be ignored and the
>   rollback will continue. However, the machine might n ot fully revert
>   to its initial state after the rollback is complete.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.
>
> I tried installing the service using the setup project but everytime i try and run the service it gives **Error 1053**

Comment: This is an error which happens when the user performing the install does not have authority to access the event log.  Do you have administrative privileges on that machine?

Comment: The error is that it cannot create an event log event source, due to security restrictions. Does your service try to create event logs?

Comment: @onemancat i have admin rights on the system.

Comment: @onemancat no idea what the error exactly was. As when i copied the code to a new project it started working fine :)